# How to provide multiple mapping manager for solr multiple cores in SolrNet

Tags: solrnet

I have configured 2 solr cores and trying to map to 2 different classes thru solrnet. I'm currently using Ninject but willing to change to say Windsor if it's not possible in Ninject. I'm trying to use the AllPropertiesMappingManager for mapping. Since I need to set 2 different unique keys for 2 different cores I don't know how to do the same using AllPropertiesMappingManager.

Currently without using the Mapping manager I'm getting the error: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: TranscriptId

EDIT: Error disappears after using attribute based mapping

```
var solrServers = new SolrServers {
new SolrServerElement {
    Id = "markup",
    Url = solrMarkupUrl,
    DocumentType = typeof(SolrMarkup).AssemblyQualifiedName,
},
new SolrServerElement {
    Id = "transcript",
    Url = solrTranscriptUrl,
    DocumentType = typeof(SolrTranscript).AssemblyQualifiedName,
}
};

kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Load(new SolrNetModule(solrServers));

SolrMarkupCore = kernel.Get<ISolrOperations<SolrMarkup>>("markup");
SolrTranscriptCore = kernel.Get<ISolrOperations<SolrTranscript>>("transcript");
```

Comment: I think you'll have to reassemble all SolrNet components, use SolrNetModule's source code as reference. https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Ninject.Integration.SolrNet/SolrNetModule.cs

Comment: I don't know how _IReadOnlyMappingManager_ can be bound to 2 concrete objects and how the _SetUniqueKey_ method works internally. And I feel this issue is not specific to Ninject integration and seems this is an essential feature to have in SolrNet w.r.t solr multi cores. If there's no other way I can go with attribute based mapping which is working fine.

Comment: it *is* more of a Ninject question than SolrNet. SolrNet already has everything you need for this. You just have to rewire the objects (either 'manually' or with Ninject).

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Do you know any other DI containers like Windsor or StructureMap supports this kind of mapping? If not can you give me some hint on how to do it manually?

Comment: this should get you started (untested) https://gist.github.com/mausch/5719418

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the SolrNet unit tests for Ninject with multiple cores - [NinjectMultiCoreFixtures.cs](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Ninject.Integration.SolrNet.Tests/NinjectMultiCoreFixture.cs) for a working example.

Also, if you are not using the mapping manager are you useing [Attribute](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping) based mapping to get things setup? Because you will still need to setup the mapping between your SolrMarkup and SolrTranscript classes fo things to work properly.

Comment: Unfortunately the NinjectMultiCoreFixtures.cs doesn't cover the mapping manager aspects. Ideally I want to use the [custom mapping](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/OverridingMappingMechanism). But the main problem with either custom mapping or AllPropertiesMappingManager is that we can provide only one mapping manager to the SolrNetModule but I need to map 2 different types for each solr core. And yes, temporarily I'm using attribute based mapping which is working fine but mapping manager is what I prefer and used initially when I started with a single core.